# BigQuery Table Exports

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking for the best pattern to be able to execute and export a BigQuery query result to a cloud storage bucket. I would like this to be executed when the BigQuery table is written to or modified.

I think I would traditionally setup a pubsub topic that would be written to when the table is modified, which would trigger a GCP function that is responsible for executing the query and writing the result to a GCP bucket. I just am not too confident that there isn't a better approach (more straight forward) to do this in GCP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you an approach based on `Eventarc`.

The goal is to launch a `Cloud Function` or `Cloud Run` action when the data is inserted or updated in a `BigQuery` table, [example with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events) :

```bash
SERVICE=bq-cloud-run
PROJECT=$(gcloud config get-value project)
CONTAINER="gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${SERVICE}"
gcloud builds submit --tag ${CONTAINER}
gcloud run deploy ${SERVICE} --image $CONTAINER --platform managed

gcloud eventarc triggers create ${SERVICE}-trigger \
  --location ${REGION} --service-account ${SVC_ACCOUNT} \
  --destination-run-service ${SERVICE}  \
  --event-filters type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written \
  --event-filters methodName=google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob \
  --event-filters serviceName=bigquery.googleapis.com
```

When a `BigQuery` job was executed, the `Cloud Run` action will be triggered.

Example of Cloud Run action :

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    # Gets the Payload data from the Audit Log
    content = request.json
    try:
        ds = content['resource']['labels']['dataset_id']
        proj = content['resource']['labels']['project_id']
        tbl = content['protoPayload']['resourceName']
        rows = int(content['protoPayload']['metadata']
                   ['tableDataChange']['insertedRowsCount'])
        if ds == 'cloud_run_tmp' and \
           tbl.endswith('tables/cloud_run_trigger') and rows > 0:
            query = create_agg()
            return "table created", 200
    except:
        # if these fields are not in the JSON, ignore
        pass
    return "ok", 200
```

You can apply logic based on the current dataset, table or other elements existing in the current payload.